# GROUP_CONCAT in subquery returns one row only

Tags: mysql, subquery, group-concat

I have some troubles to finish my Mysql Query to return me what I need to have. I am new to such long queries in MYSQL.

```
SELECT                              
  lang_rel_a_id, 
  lang_rel_b_id, 
  lang_rel_id, 
  tla.text_lang_t AS atext,
  lald.lang_data_lang_id AS laid,
  lald.lang_data_position AS lapp,
  lald.lang_data_font_weight AS lafw,
  lald.lang_data_font_size AS lafs,
  lald.lang_data_font_color AS lafc,
  lald.lang_data_bg_color AS labg,
  lasdf.funca AS lafunc,
  lang_ship,
  lbld.lang_data_lang_id AS lbid, 
  lbld.lang_data_position AS lbpp,
  lbld.lang_data_font_weight AS lbfw,
  lbld.lang_data_font_size AS lbfs,
  lbld.lang_data_font_color AS lbfc,
  lbld.lang_data_bg_color AS lbbg,
  tlb.text_lang_t AS btext,
  lbsdf.funcb AS lbfunc

  FROM lang_relation
      LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(text_func_t SEPARATOR ', ') AS funca
         FROM synt_data_func
          LEFT JOIN text_func ON text_func_id = synt_df_func 
        GROUP BY synt_df_lang_data
       )
       lasdf ON lang_rel_a_id = lasdf.synt_df_lang_data

       LEFT JOIN lang_data lald ON lald.lang_data_id = lang_rel_a_id
       LEFT JOIN text_lang tla  ON lald.lang_data_lang_id = tla.text_lang_id  

       LEFT JOIN 
          (SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(text_func_t SEPARATOR ', ') AS funcb
           FROM synt_data_func
           LEFT JOIN text_func ON text_func_id = synt_df_func 
           GROUP BY synt_df_lang_data
           )
           lbsdf ON lang_rel_b_id = lbsdf.synt_df_lang_data

       LEFT JOIN lang_data lbld ON lbld.lang_data_id = lang_rel_b_id
       LEFT JOIN text_lang tlb  ON lbld.lang_data_lang_id = tlb.text_lang_id

       WHERE lang_rel_a_id < lang_rel_b_id                              
       GROUP BY lang_rel_id
```

I have a relation of two languages in my lang_relation table. I need to query for each of them 2 subtables but the one of them is a relation table that contains the relation between the lang_data_id (= lang_rel_a_id OR lang_rel_b_id, = synt_df_lang_data) and text of the different language functions where multiple values are possible.

I do not understand why the group_concat in this subquery returns only one row. If I do only this query, I get all the results. But when I put it into this larger query, everything's fine but this.. is ..not.

My language_relation table

```
CREATE TABLE `lang_relation` 
(
`lang_rel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`lang_rel_a_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`lang_rel_b_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`lang_ship` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The joined lang_data

```
 CREATE TABLE `lang_data` (
`lang_data_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`lang_data_pic_key` int(11) NOT NULL,
`lang_data_position` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`lang_data_lang_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`lang_data_font_weight` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
`lang_data_font_size` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
`lang_data_font_color` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
`lang_data_bg_color` tinyint(2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And the synt_data_func. The text_table is a simple 2-column-table with id + text.

```
CREATE TABLE `synt_data_func` (
  `synt_df_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `synt_df_lang_data` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `synt_df_func` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

I tried different approachs. This seems to be the one that is the nearest of what I need. I don't know how many times I changed the GROUP BY clauses, I even tried to do the CONCAT_GROUP in the parent SELECT..

I even wonder if this is possible because the subqueries are going for 2 different IDs .. is this the problem?

Thanks for any hint in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could specify data for those tables and the query output you get for that data, and what the desired output should have been instead. A fiddle would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it. Maybe it will help somebody with a similar question. I changed my approach for this query.

```
 SELECT 
    lrel.lang_rel_pic_key,
    lrel.lang_rel_id,
    langdata_a.lascore,
    lasdf.func_a,
    langdata_a.latext,
    lasf.score_astyle,
    SUM(lasf.score_astyle) + (langdata_a.lascore) AS atotal,
    lang_ship,
    langdata_b.lbtext,
    langdata_b.lbscore,
    lbsdf.func_b,
    lbsf.bformat,
    lbsf.score_bstyle,
    SUM(lbsf.score_bstyle) + (langdata_b.lbscore) AS btotal

    FROM lang_relation lrel

    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            lald.lang_data_id,
            lafw.field_value AS lafweight,
            lafs.field_value AS lafsize,
            lafc.field_value AS laffc,
            lafbg.field_value AS lafbg,
            lapos.field_value AS laposa,
            tla.text_lang_t AS latext,
            SUM(lafw.field_value)  + (lafs.field_value)  + (lafc.field_value)  + (lafbg.field_value)  + (lapos.field_value) AS lascore
                        FROM lang_data lald 
                            LEFT JOIN text_lang tla     ON lald.lang_data_lang_id = tla.text_lang_id
                             LEFT JOIN `fields` lafw ON lald.lang_data_font_weight = lafw.field_id
                             LEFT JOIN `fields` lafs ON lald.lang_data_font_size = lafs.field_id
                             LEFT JOIN `fields` lafc ON lald.lang_data_font_color = lafc.field_id
                             LEFT JOIN `fields` lafbg ON lald.lang_data_bg_color = lafbg.field_id
                             LEFT JOIN `fields` lapos ON lald.lang_data_position = lapos.field_id
        GROUP BY lald.lang_data_id

    )
    langdata_a  ON langdata_a.lang_data_id = lrel.lang_rel_a_id

    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT sdf.synt_df_lang_data, GROUP_CONCAT(latf.text_func_t) AS func_a
                FROM  synt_data_func  sdf
                INNER JOIN text_func latf ON latf.text_func_id = sdf.synt_df_func
                GROUP BY sdf.synt_df_lang_data
        )
    lasdf   ON lasdf.synt_df_lang_data = lrel.lang_rel_a_id 

    LEFT JOIN 
        (
                SELECT  sfb.synt_format_lang_data, 
                            sfb.synt_format_fields_id, 
                            GROUP_CONCAT(sfbf.field_text SEPARATOR ', ') AS aformat,
                            SUM(sfbf.field_value) AS score_astyle
                FROM synt_format sfb
                INNER JOIN `fields` sfbf  ON sfbf.field_id = sfb.synt_format_fields_id
                GROUP BY sfb.synt_format_lang_data
         )
         lasf   ON lasf.synt_format_lang_data = lrel.lang_rel_a_id                


    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            lbld.lang_data_id,
            lbfw.field_value AS lbfweight,
            lbfs.field_value AS lbfsize,
            lbfc.field_value AS lbffc,
            lbfbg.field_value AS lbfbg,
            lbpos.field_value AS lbposa,
            tlb.text_lang_t AS lbtext,
            SUM(lbfw.field_value)  + (lbfs.field_value)  + (lbfc.field_value)  + (lbfbg.field_value)  + (lbpos.field_value) AS lbscore
                        FROM lang_data lbld 
                            LEFT JOIN text_lang tlb     ON lbld.lang_data_lang_id = tlb.text_lang_id
                             LEFT JOIN `fields` lbfw ON lbld.lang_data_font_weight = lbfw.field_id
                             LEFT JOIN `fields` lbfs ON lbld.lang_data_font_size = lbfs.field_id
                             LEFT JOIN `fields` lbfc ON lbld.lang_data_font_color = lbfc.field_id
                             LEFT JOIN `fields` lbfbg ON lbld.lang_data_bg_color = lbfbg.field_id
                             LEFT JOIN `fields` lbpos ON lbld.lang_data_position = lbpos.field_id
            GROUP BY lbld.lang_data_id

    )
    langdata_b ON langdata_b.lang_data_id = lrel.lang_rel_b_id


    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT sdfb.synt_df_lang_data, GROUP_CONCAT(lbtf.text_func_t) AS func_b
                FROM  synt_data_func  sdfb
                INNER JOIN text_func lbtf ON lbtf.text_func_id = sdfb.synt_df_func
                GROUP BY sdfb.synt_df_lang_data
        )
    lbsdf   ON lbsdf.synt_df_lang_data = lrel.lang_rel_b_id


    LEFT JOIN 
        (
                SELECT  sfb.synt_format_lang_data, 
                            sfb.synt_format_fields_id, 
                            GROUP_CONCAT(sfbf.field_text SEPARATOR ', ') AS bformat,
                            SUM(sfbf.field_value) AS score_bstyle
                FROM synt_format sfb
                    INNER JOIN `fields` sfbf  ON sfbf.field_id = sfb.synt_format_fields_id
                GROUP BY sfb.synt_format_lang_data
         )
         lbsf   ON lbsf.synt_format_lang_data = lrel.lang_rel_b_id



    GROUP BY lrel.lang_rel_id
```

Maybe a bit long, but output is exactly what was needed :-)